# In maatwebsite excel import start reading from given column name

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

The excel which I'm trying to import having has some junk information (like some logos, small information table, etc) in the initial rows and actual table start from row number 14.

[image]

If I try to import with the junk information it is returning all empty information as below

```
Maatwebsite\Excel\Collections\RowCollection Object
(
    [heading:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
            .
            .
            .
        )

    [title:protected] => Agent Servicing Excel
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => Maatwebsite\Excel\Collections\CellCollection Object
                (
                    [title:protected] => 
                    [items:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                )

            [1] => Maatwebsite\Excel\Collections\CellCollection Object
                (
                    [title:protected] => 
                    [items:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                )

            [2] => Maatwebsite\Excel\Collections\CellCollection Object
                (
                    [title:protected] => 
                    [items:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                )
            .
            .
            .

        )

)
```

If I start from the actual table row number using code `config(['excel.import.startRow' => 14]);`, thats works perfectly for me, but the row number may change.

So, I want to start import from given table column name say (user_name) from which my actual table starts.

Please guide me if there is any way available, Thank you.

Comment: Any success, I have same problem

Comment: Me too. I have same problem. I have been looking for a solution to this

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this way . instead of 11 your  $varialbe.

```
 Config::set('excel::import.startRow', $varialbe);
```

Comment: The row number may change, I already mentioned in the question :)

Comment: This number can be know if we manually open the excel and check from which row the table (or the column: `user_name`) is starting..

Comment: table column names are static? if so loop through data , can find user_name

Comment: yes the column name is static, but with out removing the junk information I'm getting empty data (see above)